# How to make tab insert spaces in pico?

Tags: editors, whitespace

Most text editors have a setting for converting tabs to spaces. How would this be done in pico?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a direct answer, but in case Pico can't do this, how about [Nano](http://www.nano-editor.org/)?

Quoting [its man page](http://man.he.net/man1/pico):

> nano  is  a small, free and friendly editor which **aims to replace Pico**,
>          the default editor included in the non-free Pine package.  Rather  than
>          just  copying  Pico's  look and feel, nano also implements some missing
>          (or disabled by default) features in Pico, such as "search and replace"
>          and "go to line and column number".

...and, more importantly,

```
   -E (--tabstospaces)
          Convert typed tabs to spaces.
[...]
   -T cols (--tabsize=cols)
          Set  the  size  (width)  of a tab to cols columns.  The value of
          cols must be greater than 0.  The default value is 8.
```

**Edit** As manatwork pointed out (see comments), these can be set in the config, [`nanorc`](http://man.he.net/man5/nanorc):

```
   set tabsize n
      Use a tab size of n columns.  The value of n must be greater than 0.
      The default value is 8.

   set/unset tabstospaces
      Convert typed tabs to spaces.
```

Comment: You could also mention `set tabsize n` and `set/unset tabstospaces`, maybe even quote the relevant parts of man nanorc.

Comment: Perfect. I don't care about nano vs pico, I just need a friendly terminal editor that kids can use.